# EntityFramework, Dates and UTC

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime, datetimeoffset

I have an entity with a DateTimeOffset (since .NET doesn't have a Date class) that is supposed to store a date (no time).

The problem is that, when I set the date to, for example, "2017-9-1" in the database it's saved as "2017-08-31 22:00:00+00" (2 hours less)

I think it applies the offset of my time zone to UTC.

I would like to store like to store "2017-9-1" in the database. The first thing I thought is to add 2 hours to every DateTimeOffet, but it feels bogus.

Is there a better way to work with dates than this?

Comment: How exactly do you set the date to "2017-9-1"?

Comment: Use [DateTimeOffset.Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.date(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, but add "0:" before the date on the format string, I think that should put it to your current time, otherwise it will default to UTC.

Like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/dd/MM}")]
```

Comment: That's regarding the display only, right? I would like to store the exact date in the Database.

Comment: I don't think so, it stores my current time in my db. Having a bit of a db issue myself ATM so I can't check for sure, but I think it goes for db as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS Sql, you can use the Date variable to store just date. You can annotate the entities DateTimeOffset property database type.

```
[Column(TypeName="date")]
```

Comment: I believe it does... https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html